# php crashes calling strtotime or date function

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd

My cross-compile php crashes after calling strtotime or date function. I am using cross-compile php and lighthttpd. And it shows below log

> 1969-12-31 16:37:20: (mod_fastcgi.c.2562) unexpected end-of-file (perhaps the fastcgi process died): pid: 2032 socket: unix:/tmp/php.socket-3
>   1969-12-31 16:37:20: (mod_fastcgi.c.3346) response not received, request sent: 2130 on socket: unix:/tmp/php.socket-3 for /NMS/ajaxfiles/getPMIPPacketAndProcStatSGW.php?, closing connection

Any idea?

Also I enabled date during php cross-compilation.

Comment: $arrNMSLog["log_date"] = strtotime("now");

Comment: $arrData["pass_change_date"] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Comment: Please post your whole code in the question, otherwise we can't help you.